# Send data from database to another page using tap event not working

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

What I am trying to do is, after searching for an event and tap on it, the user has to be redirected to another page called event page where all the details of the tapped event will be displayed. But it is not working I got the following error

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'NGO_Volunteer_Comm_Platform_v1._0.DataModel.Event'.
```

I did try something similar before but it is not working with the tap event

Here are my codes:

xaml:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="19,72,19,0">

    <!--<ScrollViewer>-->
    <ListBox Background="Black"  x:Name="listBox" FontSize="26" Margin="0,10,0,0" LayoutUpdated="listbox_layoutUpdate" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtEventName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" Tapped="txtEventName_Tapped" IsTapEnabled="True" Foreground="White" Width="300" Margin="10,15,0,0" Height="55"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <!--</ScrollViewer>-->
</Grid>
```

xaml.cs:

```
private void txtEventName_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(EventPage), e.Handled);
    //MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("open");
    //await md.ShowAsync();
}
```

The page where the user should be navigated to xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{   
    var b = (Event)e.Parameter;
    eventid = b.Id;
    txtName.Text = b.EventName;
    txtDate.Text = b.Date.Date.ToString();
    //txtTime.Text = b.StartingTIme.TimeOfDay.ToString();
    txtLocation.Text = b.Location;
    txtDescription.Text = b.Desc;
}
```

Comment: You pass *e.Handeled* as a parameter which is boolean type, not *Event* - you will surely get an invalid cast exception. What do you try to achieve?

Comment: when i click on the textbox that show the event i have to navigate to the event page where all its information are displayed

Answer (score 1):

e.Handled is a bool property that says if the event should propagate further down or up the visual tree. When you don't want the event to propagate, you set this property to true to say that the event was handled.

You need to send your data, and not this bool.

To do this, you should get the DataContext and send that as parameter.

```
private void txtEventName_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Event ev = (sender as TextBlock).DataContext as Event;
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(EventPage), ev);
}
```

Comment: i am trying the code, just waiting for my emulator to load

Comment: its working i do not get the same error but i get a null referrence maybe its not retrieveing the id of the event

Comment: @user3411961 When you do Frame.Navigate(typeof(EventPage), ev);, can you put a break point and see if ev is not null? Where do you see the null reference exception?

Comment: on the event page xaml.cs, the last codes i have inserted in my question.

Comment: @user3411961  Well you have to investigate yourself what is causing the null reference exception, we cannot guess. Does the event have all the data (for example, the Date property)? Or are you setting the Text property on TextBlocks/TextBoxes too early (in OnNavigateTo event handler instead of in Loaded event handler etc.)?

Comment: yes the event has all the data. i have place a brake point at ev and i get ev null.

Comment: for the OnNavigateTo it works fine when i click on an event it redirect me directly on the page. my issues is that when i search for an event and i tap on it i now get the null reference